# Adobe Air: Drag causes weird Application Crash

Tags: apache-flex, list, drag-and-drop, air

this is weird:
I created a mx:List and using an mx:Canvas with some Items as ItemRenderer. Everything works fine, the List is displayed correctly.
Now I set dragEnabled="true", dropEnabled="true" and dragMoveEnabled="true" to archive the ability to reorder my Items via Drag and Drop.

But as soon as I start to Drag an Item the whole Application crashes with:

```
Error: Error #3200: Cannot perform operation on closed window.
at Error$/throwError()
at flash.display::NativeWindow/get minSize()
at mx.core::Window/get minWidth()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\airframework\src\mx\core\Window.as:859]
at flash.utils::ByteArray/writeObject()
at flash.desktop::Clipboard/putSerialization()
at flash.desktop::Clipboard/convertFlashFormat()
at flash.desktop::Clipboard/setData()
at mx.managers::NativeDragManagerImpl/doDrag()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\airframework\src\mx\managers\NativeDragManagerImpl.as:282]
at mx.managers::DragManager$/doDrag()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\DragManager.as:243]
at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/dragStartHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\listClasses\ListBase.as:9085]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9298]
at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/mouseMoveHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\listClasses\ListBase.as:8822]
```

I don't understand why this is happening.
The mx:List lies in an custom Component, which is embedded in the Applications main window.

Comment: Error says that your window is closed - what are the chances of that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar crash issue. Is it consistent? Do you have any scrollable lists or data grids?
In my case, there was an element at the bottom of the list that was ~1/3 displayed. When the list was shorter, it didn't happen.